# cerrar un formulario desde otro formulario

Tags: c#, formularios

Tengo un problema, tengo dos formularios Form1 y Form2 en el Form1 tengo un botón que al pulsarlo me cierra el Form2. el código que he echo no funciona alguien me podría decir como hacerlo?
ese es mi código:

```
private void button_cerarGroupes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    F2.Close();           
}
```

Comment: Y que es lo que quieres hacer que se cierre o no se cierre

Comment: el formulario 2 es lo que quieroque se cierre

Comment: Los formularios son clases como cualquier otra clase.. si haces new, es un nuevo formulario, no el que vos querias cerrar...

Comment: @NguemaAutomobile, hola podrías decirme si la respuesta dada te fue útil, gracias

Answer (score 1):

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
```

estas creando una nueva instancia del *Form 2* llamado "f2" (minúscula)
en ningún momento muestras este formulario

```
F2.Close();
```

Por otro lado, estas cerrando otra instancia del formulario "F2" (mayúscula)
Asumo que tienes esa otra instancia definida globalmente.

Debería ver todo el código del formulario para analizar el caso en detalle, así como esta eso no debería ni compilar.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer esto te propongo usar el **patrón Singleton**. En pocas palabras el **patrón Singleton** garantiza que el objeto(en este caso tu formulario) sea creado una sola vez.

Para utilizar este patrón debes hacer algunas modificaciones en tu **Form2**:

- Declarar una variable de tipo **Form2**.
- Cambiar el modificador de acceso del constructor de la **clase Form2** de **public** a **private**.
- Crear un **método estático** que va a ser el encargado de instanciar la
  **clase Form2** ya que al ser el constructor privado no vas a poder invocarlo directamente sino a través de este método.

Este sería tu código:

```
private static Form2 frm2 = null;

private Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public static Form2 GetForm2()
{
    frm2 = frm2 ?? new Form2();
    return frm2;
}
```

Ahora bien, el **método GetForm2()** va a preguntar si la **variable frm2** es nula(no se ha creado), de ser nula pues se construye el **Form2**, de no ser nula quiere decir que ya fue creado, por lo que no hay que volverlo a crear. En ambos casos se retorna a **frm2**. Para lograr esto se usa al **operador ??**, el cual hace más compacto al código.

Un código alternativo al uso del **operador ??** podría ser:

```
if(frm2 == null)
{
   frm2 = new Frm2();
} 

return frm2;
```

Pues bien, ahora vamos a mostrar y cerrar a **Form2** desde el **Form1**. Imagino que tengas quizás dos botones en el **Form1**, uno para mostrar al **Form2** y otro para cerrarlo. El botón cerrar estaría inhabilitado ya que si no has mandado a mostrar el formulario no tendría sentido cerrarlo. Para inhabilitar este botón lo seleccionas y vas al cuadro de herramientas buscas la **propiedad Enabled** y la pones en **false**, o puedes poner este codigo en **evento Load** del **Form1**:

```
btnCerrar.Enabled = false;
```

Ambas formas son equivalentes.

En **Form1** creo una **variable global** de tipo **Form2**:

```
Form2 frm = null;
```

Para mostrar el **Form2** desde el **Form1** sería poner este código en tu hipotético **botón Mostrar**:

```
frm2 = Form2.GetForm2();
btnCerrar.Enabled = true; //Una vez creado el Form2, activo al botón de Cerrar
frm2.Show();
```

Fíjate como no se usa **new Form2()**, ya que el constructor es privado y no se puede usar directamente.

Para cerrar el **Form2** tendrías que poner este código en tu **botón Cerrar**:

```
frm2 = Form2.GetForm2();
btnCerrar.Enabled = false; //Desactivo el botón ya que cerré el formulario y se activaría nuevamente al mostrarlo
frm2.Close();
```

Para que entiendas mejor te dejo una imagen del código con un antes y un después de las modificaciones al **Form2**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo que busques más información sobre el **patrón Singleton**, puede serte muy útil en futuros desarrollos.

Comment: ya lo solucione gracias